# Proving that $||v||=\sqrt{2v_1^2+3v_2^2}$ defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

To prove a norm, I have to show 3 things:

> for all $v,w\in V$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> **(1)** $||v||\ge 0$ along with $||v||=0$ iff $v=\textbf{0}$
>
> **(2)** $||cv||=|c|*||v||$
>
> **(3)** $||v+w||\le ||v||+||w||$

I have questions about **(2)** and **(3)**.

**(2)** I believe this can be proven by: $||cv||=\sqrt{2(cv_1)^2+3(cv_2)^2}=\color{red}{|c|}\sqrt{2v_1^2+3v_2^2}$ (I'm only ***questioning if I should have $c_1,c_2$ instead of just $c$***)?

**(3)** I'm ***wondering if there's a quick way to prove the triangle inequality*** because I ended up doing a fair amount of algebra to end up with $48v_1w_1v_2w_2\le 24v_2^2w_1^2+24v_1^2w_2^2$ which may be true? The RHS is always $>0$?

Comment: Try to find an invertible matrix $A$ such that $\|v\| = \|Av\|_2$. With this it is clear that $\|\cdot\|$ us a norm.

Comment: Be careful: $\sqrt{2(cv_1)^2+3(cv_2)^2} = \color{red}{|c|} \sqrt{2v_1^2+3v_2^2}$ because $\sqrt{c^2} = |c|$.

Comment: @azif00 yes, thank you

Comment: Alternative, you can check that $$(v, w):=2v_1w_1+3v_2w_2$$ defines an inner product, which is trivial given the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(2, 3)$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Justauser We were recently introduced to positive definite matrices, I think that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **(2)** I believe this can be proven by: $||cv||=\sqrt{2(cv_1)^2+3(cv_2)^2}=c\sqrt{2v_1^2+3v_2^2}$ (I'm only ***questioning if I should have $c_1,c_2$ instead of just $c$***)?

No, a single $c$ is what you need. The axiom $(2)$ is about scalar multiplication, which involves a single scalar multiplying all components of the vector $v$.

> **(3)** I'm ***wondering if there's a quick way to prove the triangle inequality*** because I ended up doing a fair amount of algebra to end up with $48v_1w_1v_2w_2\le 24v_2^2w_1^2+24v_1^2w_2^2$ which may be true? The RHS is always $>0$?

It is true. Your inequality is equivalent to:
$$24(v_1^2w_1^2 - 2v_1w_1v_2w_2 + v_2^2w_2^2) \ge 0,$$
which is precisely,
$$24(v_1w_1 - v_2w_2)^2 \ge 0.$$

Alternatively, if you're happy to accept that the Euclidean norm $\|v\|_2 = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}$ satisfies $(3)$, you can write $\|v\| = \|Tv\|_2$, where $T(v_1, v_2) = (\sqrt{2}v_1, \sqrt{3}v_2)$. Then $T$ is linear, so,
$$\|v + w\| = \|T(v + w)\|_2 = \|Tv + Tw\|_2 \le \|Tv\|_2 + \|Tw\|_2 = \|v\| + \|w\|.$$

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a more perfect answer, thank you